# Python Pure RMSE vs Sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, scikit-learn

I believe I'm making an error in my calculation of RMSE in pure python.  Below is code.

```
y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]
y_pred = [2.5, 0.0, 2, 8]
e = abs(np.matrix(y_pred) - np.matrix(y_true)).A1
ee = np.dot(e,e)
np.sqrt(ee.sum()/3)

This returns: 0.707
```

However when I try with Sklearn

```
mean_squared_error(np.matrix(y_true),np.matrix(y_pred))**0.5
This returns: 0.612
```

Any idea what is going on?  Pretty sure the my python code is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not making an error.  You're dividing by `3` and `sklearn` is dividing by `4`

```
y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]
y_pred = [2.5, 0.0, 2, 8]
e = abs(np.matrix(y_pred) - np.matrix(y_true)).A1
ee = np.dot(e,e)
np.sqrt(ee.sum()/4)

0.61237243569579447
```

Dividing by `n-1` gives you an unbiased estimation and is used when calculating 2nd moments for samples.  When calculating these same moments for populations, we divide by `n`.  Here is are links that could be relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator) [Some other link](http://www.animatedsoftware.com/statglos/sgunbias.htm)

Comment: @cloud36 : Look at my answer

Answer (score 2):

The right formula of the RMSE is :

[image: RMSE]

Or in your case, `n=len(y_pred)=len(y_true)=4`.
So in order to have the right result, change `np.sqrt(ee.sum()/3)` to `np.sqrt(ee.sum()/len(y_pred))`